# Apps Script chart dashboard binding to Google Spreadsheet as data source

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

It says in the [charts dashboard tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard) that the dashboard can be bound to a Google Spreadsheet range as a data source. But this was not demonstrated in the tutorial, nor could I find relevant info in the [Apps Script docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_datatable). It seems that Datatable cannot be bound to a spreadsheet range, as the methods only provide for adding rows and columns manually.

Does anyone know how to bind the dashboard to a range from Google Spreadsheet?

In my current code, I am assuming that the dashboard can be bound to a range from Google Spreadsheet like so, but the setDataTable function call is giving me a hard time.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
var data = ss.getRangeByName("DataWithColHeadings");
var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
  .setDataTable(data) // throws error here! I think it is expecting a DataTableBuilder
  .bind([durationFilter, lineFilter], [pieChart, tableChart])
  .build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the data range using dot notation:

```
var datasource = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName").getRange("A1:J20");
```

And then use it as follows:

```
var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
      .setDataTable(**datasource**)
```

When used this way, you can eliminate the code specifying column names and row values. Just make sure that the values in the specified range are consistent and non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is the equivalent of the tutorial bound to named range in spreadsheet. Named range includes the column heads.

```
    function doGet() {
      var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();
      var ssKey = "0At0FGJizRd-gdFo5bWZUUFRrUnRabENiRFdmT2o4WUE";
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssKey);
      var datasource = ss.getRangeByName("myRange").getValues();
      Logger.log(datasource);
      var data = Charts.newDataTable()
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, datasource [0] [0])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, datasource [0] [1])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [2])
          .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, datasource [0] [3])
          for (i=1;i<=datasource.length-1;i++){
        Logger.log(datasource [i]);
        data.addRow([datasource [i] [0], datasource [i] [1], datasource [i] [2], datasource [i] [3]])
          };

      data.build();
      var ageFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter()
          .setFilterColumnLabel("Age")
          .build();

      var genderFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
          .setFilterColumnLabel("Gender")
          .build();

      var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
          .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
                         .setColumns([0,3]))
          .build();

      var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
          .build(); 
      var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
          .setDataTable(data)
          .bind([ageFilter, genderFilter], [pieChart, tableChart])
          .build();
      dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
            .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                 .add(ageFilter).add(genderFilter)
                 .setSpacing(70))
            .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
                 .add(pieChart).add(tableChart)
                 .setSpacing(10)));
      uiApp.add(dashboard);
      return uiApp;
    }
```

Comment: It would have been a probably better idea to pinpoint the error in the question rather than throwing a complete code without any explanation...

Comment: Hey David thanks so much! I understand now that I still need to use DataTable, but I have to populate the DataTable first with the range of values from the spreadsheet. It would be cool if we could skip DataTable entirely and just call the setDataSourceUrl function, which unfortunately cannot handle ampersands in the url for now (for those interested, please star [link] issue 1304 (http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1304))

Comment: Dashboard was new to me, so I was interested in seeing a working usage ... sorry if too much redundant detail. The issue 1304 seems fixed but setDataSourceUrl is not available for dashboard (yet?)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the API function of the object RANGE called .getDataTable(). The below example works on my two-column, multi-row sheet.

```
function doGet() {
   var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("My Dashboard");

   var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
   var dataTable = dataRange.getDataTable(true);

   var catFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
       .setFilterColumnLabel("Category")
       .build();

   var chart = Charts.newPieChart()
       .build();

   var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
       .setDataTable(dataTable)
       .bind([catFilter], [chart])
       .build();

   var panel = uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
     .add(chart)
     .add(catFilter);

   dashboard.add(panel);
   uiApp.add(dashboard);
   return uiApp;
}
```

Comment: There remain 2 questions regarding my own answer actually.
1. I must bind the data to the chart through filter, even though I do not want a filter.  Why must I have a filter in the .bind command?
2. I must also show the filter via the .add(catFilter) command.  Otherwise, I get a "Google Drive has encountered an error." message when I run the script.  Why must I also show the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Attached is an example where the Applescript intuitively gets a data range starting in cell A1 of the first sheet in a google spreadsheet.

This is my first stackoverflow answer, so please give feedback

I have recreated the google piechart [Applescript dashboard tutorial](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard) modified for referencing a spreadsheet below:

```
    function doGet() {
    var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication();
    // type the SpreadsheetKey below within quotes for 
    // example "1MfXR_ELFevumQwEOjWneNL5j2M8aVLgELBOsS41LD5o"
    var ssKey = "1MfXR_ELFevumQwEOjWneNL5j2M8aVLgELBOsS41LD5o";
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssKey);
    var dataRange = ss.getDataRange();
    var data = dataRange.getDataTable(true);

    var ageFilter = Charts.newNumberRangeFilter()
        .setFilterColumnLabel("Age")
        .build();

    var genderFilter = Charts.newCategoryFilter()
        .setFilterColumnLabel("Gender")
        .build();

    var pieChart = Charts.newPieChart()
        .setDataViewDefinition(Charts.newDataViewDefinition()
        .setColumns([0,3]))
        .build();

    var tableChart = Charts.newTableChart()
        .build(); 

    var dashboard = Charts.newDashboardPanel()
        .setDataTable(data)
        .bind([ageFilter, genderFilter], [pieChart, tableChart])
        .build();  
    dashboard.add(uiApp.createVerticalPanel()
          .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
               .add(ageFilter).add(genderFilter)
               .setSpacing(70))
          .add(uiApp.createHorizontalPanel()
               .add(pieChart).add(tableChart)
               .setSpacing(10)));
    uiApp.add(dashboard);
    return uiApp;
    }
```